# Function to copy file on a remote service

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have written the below function to copy file on a remote server

```
Function deploy-file{
PARAM(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)][STRING]$cred,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][STRING]$server,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][STRING]$destdir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)][STRING]$file
)

    $parameters = @{
        Name = $server
        PSProvider = "FileSystem"
        Root = $destdir
        Credential = $cred
    }
    new-psdrive @parameters
    $d=$server + ":\"           
    copy-item $file $d -force
    
    remove-psdrive $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Now, I am calling the above function from the main file as below:

```
$sn=abc.com
$server=($sn -split "\.")[0]
$destdir = 'e:\folder'
$file = 'file.zip'
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $usr, $pa
deploy-file $cred $server $destdir $file
```

There is no issue with credentials.

My script keeps running and not even throwing any error. What is wrong with the script?

Comment: Have you tried running the code line by line without a function involved and see where it fails? Also, it might be a much easier alternative to use a PSSession

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon can you please provide the script with `PSSession`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon okay. I need your help to update the script with `unc path` as i have never used it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copying a file to a remote host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-5--copy-a-file-to-a-remote-computer) using a `PSSession` would be as follows:

```
function Deploy-File {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
        [securestring] $cred,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
        [string] $server,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2)]
        [string] $destdir,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=3)]
        [string] $file
    )
    
    try {
        [IO.FileInfo] $file = Get-Item $file
        $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred
        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $destdir -ToSession $session
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
    finally {
        if($session) {
            Remove-PSSession $session
        }
    }
}
```

By looking at your code is hard to tell what could be failing aside from what we know for sure is incorrect, the parameter `$cred` is being constrained to `[string]` when it actually should be `[securestring]`. By doing so you're rendering your PS Credential object unusable.

Comment: The script is working fine. can I rename the file using the command `move-item $destdir\$af_src_file $deploy_dir\$target --ToSession $session`.  I basically want to add `timestamp` to the `file name`

Comment: @meallhour `Move-Item` doesnt have a `-ToSession` parameter, if you want to copy the file to the remote host with a different name pass the full path of the file to the `$destdir` parameter, `-destdir E:\someremotefolder\newfilename.ext`